# Get Total unique count of some records from two tables

Tags: sql-server

We have two tables, Status and Main.

Status table:

```
statusId int pk
Status nvarchar(100)
```

Sample data

```
1                 Open
2                 Cancelled
3                 Under Review
4                 Awarded
5                 Archived
6                 Closed
7                 Removed
8                 Library CM Subcontractor
9                 Property Sales
```

Main table:

```
statusid int fk to Status table
Type nvarchar(50)
```

Sample data

```
StatusID                   Type
1                          Bid
1                          Quote
1                          RFP
```

We are trying to get a count of **current** Type from main table and a count of Status from Status table  and display the results in the following format:

```
Current [count]
Current Bid [count]
Current RFP [count]
Sole Source [count]
Library CM Subcontracting [count]
Current Quotes [count]
Property Sales [count]
Closed [count]
Cancelled [count]
Under Review [count]
Awarded [count]
Archives [count]
```

The word count in square brackets represent the total number of records for a particular fieldname.

My code so far, produces the count of current Bids, current Quotes and current RFPs from the main table.

However, my count of Status are getting duplicated.

Below is the code I am using:

```
select
       case when status.status ='Open' then Main.Type else status.status end as Name
     , count(*) as total
from Main
inner join status on Main.Bidstatus = status.statusid
group by
       case when status.status ='Open' then Main.Type else status.status end
     , Main.Type
```

Any idea how to modify the code to produce unique counts of the records?

Comment: Your current results can not be explained from the sample data you have provided. The definition of the Main table does not match the SQL query.

Comment: @RhysJones, hi. I don't understand your point at all.

Comment: You are grouping on the case statement and 'Main.Type'. So add 'Main.Type' to your select statement to see that they are not actually duplicates but have different 'Main.Type' values

Comment: @TamerM, Ok I understand now.

This goes to show that I probably didn't explain myself very well.

Each bid, quote, or rfp have open, archived, cancelled, removed, closed, Under Review statuses.

We would just like two things:

1, Get a count of all current bids, quotes and RFPs. This I stated correctly earlier.

2, Then a count of total archives, Under Reviews, Awarded, Cancelled, etc.

In other words, a total unique count of each status while getting a count of current bids, rfps and quotes under the Type fieldname.

This is a complex query from my point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still not very clear, your requirements keep changing. However, if you need the total count of the main type records and a total count of the  substatus records, you can use the following queries separated or UNIONed depending on what you need:

```
SELECT Main.Type Name , 
   COUNT( * )AS Count
FROM Main
   INNER JOIN status ON Main.Bidstatus = status.statusid
GROUP BY Main.Type

--optional:
--UNION

SELECT status.statusid Name , 
   COUNT( * )AS Count
FROM Main
   INNER JOIN status ON Main.Bidstatus = status.statusid
GROUP BY status.statusid
```

Comment: I sincerely apologize. You guys raised some important questions that forced me to clarify the requirements.

Your query has gotten so close to the finish line.

The only thing left, if your kindness will persist is to get count of current records.

Current, as indicated, means where Status is Open.

We got pretty accurately the count of all the stuff I was looking for except count of current records.

Thanks so much.

Comment: If i understood correctly, just copy the first SELECT statement and add a WHERE statement: "WHERE status.status = 'Open'".

Comment: When you understand GROUPING really well, I suggest you read more about GROUPING SETS. They be quite useful.